# how to check for numbers in a certain position in a string and extracting its value in c?

Tags: c, string

I'm supposed to write a function not using other libraries but  that gets a string from a user (up to 100 chars). the string would be in this form: a,b,c,d,x,y,z etc... from which i'm supposed to extract only the first whole numbers in between commas to a different array.
so for example let's say i get this as an input: abcd,32,23.5,4,6,hf3,45g,2
the numbers in the new array should be: 32,4,6,2 because these are the first 4 numbers you can see in the input. if there was no number found the default value will be 0.

this is what i've been doing so far, but somehow it doesn't seem to be right,
the idea was to check each char seperately, and unless a comma was seen and the char is between the ASCII value of '0' and '9' to sum them. if a different char was seen before the comma, then "skip" will get the value 1, this way the function will keep looking for another number.

thanks for the help.

```
int getParameters()
{
  char input[100];
  int parameters[4]={0};
  int indexInput=0, indexParameters;
  int charValue=0;
  int skip=1;
  scanf("%s", input);

  for (indexParameters=0; indexParameters<4;skip=0)
  {
    if (input[indexInput]=='\0')
      break;
    else
    {
      for (;input[indexInput]!=','; ++indexInput)
      {
        printf("%c\n", input[indexInput]);
        if(input[indexInput]=='\0')
          break;
        else if (input[indexInput]<'9' && 
                 input[indexInput]>'0')
        {
          charValue=input[indexInput]-'0';
          parameters[indexParameters]*=10;
          parameters[indexParameters]+=charValue;
        }
        else
        {
          skip=1;
        }
      }
    }
    indexInput++;
    if (input[indexInput]==",")
      skip==1;
    if (skip==1)
    {
      parameters[indexParameters]=0;
    }
    else
      indexParameters++;
    }
  return 0;
  }
```

Comment: _but somehow it doesn't seem to be right._ How exactly? The expected output is 32, 4, 6, 2. What is the output you get?

Comment: The line `if (input[indexInput]==",") skip==1;` certainly should be `if (input[indexInput] == ',') skip = 1;`: You assign 1 to `skip` and you test against a cahacter (in single quotes).

Comment: Also, you exclude 0 and 9 from your digits.

Comment: it seems like somehow i exceed the limit of the array and get strange numbers.

Comment: With the input you gave above? I can't reproduce that. How do you call the function? Your parameters are local. Do you have a global aray alongside that that you expect to be filled?

Comment: no, i'm trying to work on it in a different way again :(

Answer (score 2):

sample by `strtok` and `strtol`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    char input[100] = "abcd,32,23.5,4,6,hf3,45g,2";
    char *token = strtok(input, ",");

    while(token){
        char *endp;
        int num = strtol(token, &endp, 10);
        if(*endp == '\0')
            printf("%d\n", num);
        //else //not integer.

        token = strtok(NULL, ",");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

without `strtok`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    char input[100] = "abcd,32,23.5,4,6,hf3,45g,2";
    char *p = input;

    while(*p){
        char *endp;
        int num = strtol(p, &endp, 10);
        if(*endp == ',' || *endp == '\0')
            printf("%d\n", num);
        //else //not integer.
        //skip to next read point    
        p = endp;
        while(*p != ',' && *p)
            ++p;
        if(*p)
            ++p;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: great way of solving it but this time i wasn't allowed to use <string.h>

Comment: @Ryan sample add without `<string.h>`

Answer (score 1):

solved the problem, tried a different algorithm just with one loop:

```
int getParameters()
{
  char input[100];
  int parameters[4]={0};
  int indexInput=0, indexParameters=0;
  int skip=0, numberSeen=0;
  scanf("%s", input);

for (;input[indexInput]!='\0' && indexParameters<4;++indexInput)
{
  if (input[indexInput]==',' && skip==1)
  {
    parameters[indexParameters]=0;
    skip=0;
  }
  else if (input[indexInput]==','&& numberSeen==1)
  {
    numberSeen=0;
    indexParameters++;
  }
  else if (input[indexInput]==',')
    continue;
  else if (input[indexInput]<='9' && input[indexInput]>='0')
  {
    parameters[indexParameters]*=10;
    parameters[indexParameters]+=input[indexInput]-'0';
    numberSeen=1;
  }
  else
    skip=1;
}

return 0;
}
```